# Autofill of StrFormulas not Working

Tags: excel, vba

I hope someone can help me.  I'm pretty new to VBA and completely self-taught, using forums such as this.  I have a workbook with 4 sheets, the first 3 are visible, the 4th is hidden:

1. Dashboard - contains command buttons for executing vba codes I've created.  Cell F6 contains the number of rows with data on the second sheet (data)
2. Data - contains 2000 to 4000 rows of data, depending upon the codes executed;
3. ICPAS - contains 2000 to 4000 rows of data, also depending upon the codes executed;
4. Sheet1 - This will be used to identify records with errors on either the Data sheet or the ICPAS sheet.

I have created the following code with the intent to unhide Sheet1, add formulas to cells A2, B2, C2 and D2 (row 1 has headers) and fill the formulas down to the last row that is equal to the number of rows with data on the Data sheet based on the value of cell F6 on the Dashboard sheet.  When I get to ".Range("A2:D2").Formula = strformulas", my code stops and I get run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Sub addformulasSheet1()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Sheets("Dashboard")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Data = Sheets("Data")
Set lr = sh1.Range("F6")

        sh2.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        sh2.Activate

With sh2
    Dim strformulas(1 To 4) As Variant
        strformulas(1) = "=IF(OR(Data!$AW2=""Yes"",Data!$AX2=""Yes"",Data!$AY2=""Yes"",Data!$BB2=""Yes"",Data!$BM2=1,Data!$BN2=1,Data!$BO2=1,Data!$BP2=1,Data!$BQ2=1,Data!$BR2=1),Data!$F2,"""")"
        strformulas(2) = "=IF(OR(AND(ICPAS!$Q2=""No"",ICPAS!$R2=""Yes""),AND(ICPAS!$Q2=""Yes"",ICPAS!$V2=""Yes""),ICPAS!$S2=""Yes"",ICPAS!$T2=""Yes"",ICPAS!$AF2<>"""",ICPAS!$AG2<>"""",ICPAS!$AH2=1),ICPAS!$C2,"""")"
        strformulas(3) = "=IF(Data!$BH2=1,Data!$F2,"""")"
        strformulas(4) = "=IF(ICPAS!$AJ2=1,ICPAS!$C2,"")"
        .Range("A2:D2").Formula = strformulas
        .Range("P2").resize(, UBound(strformulas)) = strformulas
        .Range("A2:D" & lr).FillDown

End With

        sh2.Visible = xlSheetHidden


End Sub
```

Comment: In your forth formula you are missing some `"`; `""` should be `""""`

Comment: Duh!  I shoulda had a V-8!  Thank you!  I looked and looked at these formulas and totally missed the """" issue.